# Regex in Google Analytics for segment creation

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm trying to trap URLs of the following structure:

```
/resources/state-name/city-name
```

given that there are URLs of the following type

```
/resources/other-words

/resources/state-name

/resources/state-name/city-name/other-words
```

I have tried to trap using
include/matches regex:

```
\/resources\/.*\/.*
```

exclude/matches regex:

```
\/resources\/.*\/.*\/.*
```

but this is allowing the other-words and state-name only to slip through.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex [`\/resources\/[^\/\r\n]*(?:$|(?:\/.*\/.*$))`](https://regex101.com/r/wQEFqY/2). I assumed the end of the url was also the end of the line. This matches all of them but `/resources/state-name/city-name`

To only get `/resources/state-name/city-name`, then use this one [`\/resources\/[^\/\r\n]*\/[^\/\r\n]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/wQEFqY/3).

Comment: Its closer. But this picks up   /resources/state-name/city-name/other-words

Comment: Do you want to get only `/resources/state-name/city-name`? If you do then I just did the opposite of that haha. Updated my answer

Comment: This basically worked, although Google appears to do some odd things with Regex.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this `/(\/resources\/)([\w+%-]+)\/([\w+%-]+)/g`

With this `[\w-%]` you match any letter, number, - and % in the URL (i put % because in the URLs spaces are replaced with `-` or `+` or `%20`)

Also, with the `()` you can access each member with `$1` to `$3`